# iPhone signal that button opens a modal

Tags: iphone

Most of the examples I find are all web designated and I don't necessarily believe they apply to native iPhone development.  Also, forgive my ignorance for such as I am quite green to native app development.

I am looking for a way to designate that pressing a button/view will open up a modal. I currently have something like such

[image]

which gives the look of a web dropdownlist which I don't necessarily agree with.

I thought about something like this with a button of "Change Roadway"

[image]

I've reviewed the iOS interface guidelines but I didn't find anything specific to how to designate an action opens a modal. What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OSX (Windows too, I imagine) an ellipsis signifies that more info is needed to complete the command. This is often gathered in a modal. So something as simple as changing your button to "Change Roadway..." might help.

[image: dropdown menu]

Honestly, though, I think your solution is fine as-is.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the feedback. Didn't even think about the ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

Although modals are used on mobiles, they have more justification if presented as an overlay for short informative or confirmation messages.

There is quite a bit out there on cons of using all but minimalistic modals on mobiles (see [this blog](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/design/modal-dialog-windows-in-mobile-ui/), or [this one](http://uxmovement.com/mobile/why-you-should-avoid-using-modal-windows-on-mobile/)).

A more native UI, for the iPhone at least, will be a table view that slides in the record form to occupy the whole view. As in:

[image: Screenshot of the setting app]

Comment: Ah. This is excellent for my case since the number of items I am showing can be 10+ items.